# Quantum Computing - Conjugate Transpose and Tensor Products

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-computation

Show that $(A^T)^T = A$, where *T* is the conjugate transpose of the matrix.

$$\left|\psi\right\rangle = \alpha_0\left|0\right\rangle + \alpha_1\left|1\right\rangle\; \text{and}\;\left|\phi\right\rangle = \beta_0\left|0\right\rangle + \beta_1\left|1\right\rangle$$
Show that $$\left|\psi\right\rangle \otimes \left|\phi\right\rangle = \alpha_0\beta_0\left|00\right\rangle + \alpha_0\beta_1\left|01\right\rangle + \alpha_1\beta_0\left|10\right\rangle + \alpha_1\beta_1\left|11\right\rangle$$

Any help on either of these would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the first problem is looking for; however, note that $(A^T)^T=A$ is a defining property of Hermitian Operators, which implies that $\langle\psi|A\phi\rangle = \langle A^T\psi|\phi\rangle =\langle A\psi|\phi\rangle $.

The second problem is easily shown using the properties of the tensor product:

For 2-dimensional vectors $|a\rangle$,$|b\rangle$:
$$
|a\rangle\otimes|b\rangle = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a_0b_0 \\
a_0b_1 \\
a_1b_0 \\
a_1b_1 \end{array} \right) 
$$

Let $|a\rangle = |\psi\rangle = \alpha_0|0\rangle + \alpha_1|1\rangle$, $|b\rangle = |\phi\rangle = \beta_0|0\rangle + \beta_1|1\rangle $.

Then:

$|a\rangle\otimes|b\rangle = |ab\rangle = (\alpha_0|0\rangle + \alpha_1|1\rangle)\otimes(\beta_0|0\rangle + \beta_1|1\rangle)$

$|ab\rangle=\alpha_0|0\rangle\otimes\beta_0|0\rangle + \alpha_0|0\rangle\otimes\beta_1|1\rangle + \alpha_1|1\rangle\otimes\beta_0|0\rangle + \alpha_1|1\rangle\otimes\beta_1|1\rangle
$

$|ab\rangle = \alpha_0\beta_0|00\rangle + \alpha_0\beta_1|01\rangle + \alpha_1\beta_0|10\rangle + \alpha_1\beta_1|11\rangle
$

Answer (score 0):

For the second one, you might be getting tripped up with notation. Note that $|00\rangle = |0\rangle\otimes|0\rangle$, $|01\rangle = |0\rangle\otimes|1\rangle$ and likewise for the others. Does this clear it up for you?

For the first one, we often define $A^T$ (conjugate transpose) by $\langle\psi, A\phi\rangle = \langle A^T\psi,\phi\rangle$. From this, how would we define $(A^T)^T$? (There are one or two more steps after this.)

Comment: I understand the notation that you specified for the first one, but I am not clear on how to begin addressing a tensor product.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you definition of $A^T = \langle\psi,A\phi\rangle$?

Comment: That is not the definition, it is just that $A^T$ is defined by the relation that $\langle A^T\psi,\phi\rangle = \langle \psi,A\phi\rangle$. This is like giving a matrix representation of $A^T$ in terms of the matrix representation of $A$.

Comment: As for how to address the tensor product, how would you evaluate $|0\rangle\otimes(\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle)$? Hint: use linearity.

Comment: So should I write: $\langle(A)\psi,\phi\rangle = \langle\psi,(A^T)^T\phi\rangle = \langle(A^T)\psi,\phi\rangle = A$?

Comment: So is that evaluated: $\alpha|00\rangle + \beta|01\rangle$?

Comment: You are right about the tensor product. Now can you see how to do that for the case above? (Hint: it's very similar..)

As for the transpose, you're partially correct. You have $\langle\psi,A\phi\rangle = \langle\psi,(A^T)^T\phi\rangle$, which is correct. Now, let's subtract a bit from both sides to get: $$\langle\psi,(A\phi-(A^T)^T\phi)\rangle = 0.$$ This holds true for all $\psi$ and $\phi$.. Particularly it holds for $\psi = A\phi-(A^T)^T\psi$, meaning that $$\langle A\phi-(A^T)^T\phi,A\phi-(A^T)^T\phi\rangle = 0.$$ Do you see what this tells you about $A\phi-(A^T)^T\phi$?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: You should accept the answer if it properly addressed your questions. Otherwise the question will periodically resurface when it shouldn't.